# How to remove space when the error for form validation doesn't show?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css, react-functional-component

I've made form validation for email using react and tailwindcss. However, even when there's no error message, there's a space for it, and that breaks the format a little. Also, it thinks "name@example" is a valid email address when it shoudln't.
Code:

```
const [showEmailError, setShowEmailError] = useState(false);
//code 
<div className='flex w-full flex-col space-y-2'>
        <label htmlFor='email' className='text-sm text-gray-600'>
          Email address
        </label>
        <input
          type='email'
          id='email'
          autoComplete='email'
          required
          className='peer relative block w-full appearance-none rounded-md border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-500 invalid:text-pink-600 focus:z-10 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none  focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:invalid:border-pink-500 focus:invalid:ring-pink-500 sm:text-sm'
          value={email}
          onChange={e => {
            setEmail(e.target.value);
            setShowEmailError(false);
          }}
          onBlur={_ => setShowEmailError(true)}
        />
        <p className={`invisible mt-2 text-sm text-pink-600 ${
            email.length > 0 && showEmailError ? 'peer-invalid:visible' : ''}`}>
          Please provide a valid email address.
</div>
```

Action:

[image]

How to fix it the 2 problems?

Comment: Don't render classes conditionally, instead render whole `<p>error message</p>` conditionally.

Comment: `invisible / visible` pair of classes sets CSS `visibility` which still [maintain](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/visibility#making-elements-invisible) its place in the DOM. You may try `hidden / block` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it with giving `position: absolute` to the tag in which you binding error. This way it will not effecting the space.

Comment: tried position:absolute, there's no extra space now, however, the "please provide a valid email address." is now displayed just under email address and it looks ugly